Override class service definition in Symfony in a specific environment with a factory
If I have a simple definition for a Guzzle client for instance in my production environment:
GuzzleHttp\Client: ~

This will ensure a guzzle client is always injectable, that works fine.
But in the dev environment I'd want to make the client with a custom factory that attaches all kinds of debugging middleware and configurations, so I'd put this in my services_dev.yml
  GuzzleHttp\Client:
    factory: ['@Factories\GuzzleFactory', 'createClient']
    arguments:
      - handler: '@custom.debugging.guzzle.stack'

That also works great, provided I directly use a GuzzleHttp\Client in my constructor.
But things start to break when I have custom services of this class, that would extend it more.
custom.client:
    class: GuzzleHttp\Client
    arguments:
      - handler: '@custom.guzzle.stack'

I'd want this custom.client to be made with the factory ONLY in the dev environment.
Even though it's defined as a class of type GuzzleHttp\Client, the GuzzleHttp\Client factory in the overridden definition is not used.
What am I doing wrong? Ideally I don't want to define the factory in my production.yml because it is purely used for adding debugging info

Can you please update your question and show the configuration for pod, dev and constructor of your service?

custom.client:
    class: GuzzleHttp\Client

In that example, the class option is not a reference to a service, so the factory won't affect this definition.
Note that it's the same for the factory definition, but you're using the FQCN as service ID. so it's equal to:
GuzzleHttp\Client:
    class: GuzzleHttp\Client
    factory: ['@Factories\GuzzleFactory', 'createClient']

To solve the original issue, you may want to use the parent option in your custom client service, like this:
custom.client:
    parent: GuzzleHttp\Client
    arguments:
      - handler: '@custom.guzzle.stack'

